# MissingMethodException with xsp4 and asp.net 4.5

Tags: mono, asp.net-4.5, xsp4

I am trying to test a web site with xsp4, all assemblies are compiled for target framework 4.5. I get the following stack trace.
Exception during TraceManager initialization:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Web.Configuration.TraceSection ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor'.
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
```

A search here on stackoverflow (and other places) found that a possible reason is that xsp4 runs within the 4.0 directory of mono. Mine is already located in 4.5 and is used by the xsp script, so I am stuck with this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. The error resulted from having a FSharp.Core.Dll within the bin folder. It is a mixed F# / C# project and a local copy is not needed, if the Dll resides within the GAC. Removing it made the error disappear.